# This is what xcode's new features, please see the picture for details

Tags: xcode

My Xcode version is 10.0 (10A255)
I found out in the official update log whether there is an introduction to this, but I did not find it.

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVwVa.jpg)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11pK7.jpg)

Comment: Where is the question? Please make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen shot shows the Code Coverage display.